# (Python) strange extra quotes appearing even after replacement

Tags: python

So basically I'm working on File/IO practice with some dictionary shenanigans and whenever I have a string inside my returning tuple value in my dictionary entry it has extra quotes even if I use .replace. It gets a little weird in the middle because in the file has a bunch of Pokemon and "stats" separated by commas and sometimes the names have a comma so I made it operate by how long the list was after the split by comma

[image]

```
def read_info_file(filename):
d={}
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    next(f)
    for line in f:
        h=line.split(',')
        if len(h)==7:
            h[1]=str(h[1]+','+h[2])
            h[2]=h[3]
            h[3]=h[4]
            h[4]=int(h[5])
            h[5]=h[6] 

            h[1].replace("\"","")
            h[2].replace("\"","")
            h[3].replace("\"","")
            h[5].replace("\"","")
            #if there are more than 5 items due to a naming convention
            #concatanate the name parts and reorder the list properly
        d[h[1]]=int(h[0]),h[2],h[3],int(h[4]),h[5]
        #final assignment
return d
```

Comment: for whatever reason my picture of the cmd didnt get in http://i.imgur.com/Z77kN49.png

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you mean the extra single-quotes around 'Bulbasaur'? That's just to indicate it's a string.

Comment: It looks like you're parsing CSV. Use [the `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), and it will handle quoted fields for you. Don't waste time reinventing CSV parsing, badly.

Comment: The first element in the `h` list is `h[0]` which you are not replacing... Is that what you mean by your strange extra qutotes?

Comment: Those don't look like standard quotes to me. These are standard: `' "` These are not: `‘’ “”`

Comment: To clarify the cmd is a tester file which shows one the bottom which it is expecting and  the top is what I have

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm obviously not trying to reinvent the wheel here bud I'm just trying to do a school assignment, not allowed to import CSV

Comment: @shadow No, there is an extra set of quotes like ' " Test " ' whenever I put a string in the tuple despite me putting in the replacement statements to get rid of the extra double quotes in the middle

Answer (score 0):

Python `str` is immutable; `str.replace` returns a new string, it doesn't change the existing string. Replaced, then threw away the result.

You need to assign the result for the quotes to be stripped, e.g. replacing:

```
h[1].replace("\"","")  # Does replace and throws away result
```

with:

```
h[1] = h[1].replace("\"","")  # Does replace and replaces original object with new object
```

Note: If you're just trying to strip leading and trailing quotes, I'd suggest `h[1] = h[1].strip('"')` which is specialized for removing characters from the ends (without checking the middle).